# Users ask for Portuguese translation despite the fact that pt and pt-rBR translations exist

Tags: android

I translate my apps to Portuguese language. After users asking for Portuguese translation despite it's already translated, i can see it's translated when i change my device's language to Portuguese, i thought maybe i need to pt-rBR folder, but it does not help either.

I asked users to send their device language, image or screenshot of the app, but after multiple tries and few weeks none of them replied back.

Does anyone experience the same issue with **Portuguese**? I really can't figure out why it happens, i tried on 3 devices and both work fine. I also translated to Spanish, and Spanish is spoken in various countries too, haven't got any issues.

Answer (score 0):

All the Portuguese strings (works for other resources too) should go to `values-pt/strings.xml` you should only use `values-pt-rPT` and `values-pt-rBR` if you have specific localizations for Portugal and Brazil respectively, otherwise (and in terms of simple localizations) they should share most elements.

Spanish is the same, you have `values-es` and then `values-es-rES` for Spain specifically, but various other Spanish-speaking countries, e.g.: `values-es-rAR` for Argentina and so forth.

French: `values-fr` or `values-fr-rCA` for Canada, etc.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

> The language is defined by a two-letter ISO 639-1 language code, optionally followed by a two letter ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 region code (preceded by lowercase "r").

Comment: I have values-pt and values-pt-BR folders now, but before users' translation requests i had only values-pt. It's a mystery to my. I don't have specific translation for a language. I use Google translate and it only translates to Portuguese.

Comment: Yes, ask your users to send you a shot. Must be user-error or some custom rom? I’ve translated multiple apps and never heard of that. Remember you should add `pt-rBR` not just `pr-BR` you need the lowercase `r` in front.

Comment: Thanks, it's not a spelling error, i'm sure of that. I tried creating values folders using Android Studio's Translation Editor too.

Comment: Yeah, that’s as much as you can do. If you set your device(s) to Portuguese (any country) it should work, because if you are in Brazil and switch to Portugal, if a translation can’t be found in `pt-rBR` or `pt-rPT` it will then try to use `pt` alone before resorting to the default in `values`. Ensure you don’t have _other_ dimensions affecting users (like size constraints / dimensions override things). If you have a crazy thing like `values-pt-h800dp-port` then that may be overriding something.

Comment: It's very weird, that i have values-pt only and in some devices it picks up portuguese but in others it just defaults to english.